# Make a knowledgeable and economic impact on users

Tags: word-choice

Let's take StackExchange for example, it help share knowledge and help software developers to debug. So I would like to say "Stack Exchange makes a knowledgeable and economic impact on users".

I think "economic impact" is correct term, but is "knowledgeable impact" a correct term?

Comment: You obviously have doubts about your suggestion, and you are right.  The somewhat metaphorical usage of the word 'impact' as a substitute for the less dramatic word like 'effect' or 'benefit' is a popular rhetorical usage - some might say too popular.  But you are right to doubt whether it is appropriate in this context.  try spelling out what it means by paraphrasing.  I assume you mean that it makes users more knowledgeable and more economically successful.  But making more economically successful is an economic impact, whereas making them more knowledgeable is not a 'knowledgeable' impact

Comment: [Continued from the above].  In fact it has an economic impact by making them (the users) more knowledgeable.  This does not make such a good sales pitch, perhaps.  You can say it makes users more knowledgeable and so more successful.

Comment: While SE has certainly made me more knowledgeable, the only economic impact its had on me is a negative one.  I could have been out making money but instead I get stuck puttering on SE...  Not that I mind.  Just sayin’

Comment: Ditto to @Jim. Not that I mind. However....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think "knowledgeable impact" works the way you would want it to here. The more common term might be "educational impact" - even though it might sound a bit too structured and academic for SE, I would say it's an apt descriptor for increasing knowledge.

"Enlightening" is another contender but it sounds too lofty